# Childbrowser plugin not working in Phonegap

Tags: ios5, cordova, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm using Backbone, Require and Underscore Bundled with Phonegap or Cordova.

I tried using the childbrowser plugin but it wont work. I followed the instructions here.
http://blog.digitalbackcountry.com/2012/03/installing-the-childbrowser-plugin-for-ios-with-phonegapcordova-1-5/

```
define([
'jquery',
'backbone',
'underscore',
'base64',
'mobile',
'const',
    'child',
'text!template/login/login.tpl.html'
],function($, Backbone, _, base64, Mobile, Const, ChildBrowser, template){

var EncodeAuth = function(user,pass)
{
    var _tok = user + ':' + pass;
    var _hash = Base64.encode(_tok);
    return "Basic "+ _hash;
}

var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events:{
    "click .login-btn" : "Login",
    "click .connection-btn" : "OpenSite"
    },

    initialize: function(){
    },

    Login: function(){
        Const.USERNAME = $("#username").val();
        Const.PASSWORD = $("#password").val();
        if(!Const.USERNAME || !Const.PASSWORD)
        {
            navigator.notification.alert("Invalid Username/Password!");
            $("input").val("");
        }else{

            var auth = EncodeAuth(Const.USERNAME,Const.PASSWORD);

            var sendAuthorization = function (xhr) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth)
            };

            this.model.save(this.model, {
                beforeSend : sendAuthorization,
                success: function(model,result){
                    if(result.ErrorMessage === null)
                    {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(result.Message));
                        $("input").val("");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(result.ErrorMessage));
                        $("input").val("");
                    }
                },
                error: function(model,result){
                    alert("Remote server returned an error. Not Found");
                    $("input").val("");
                }
            });
        }
    },
        OpenSite: function(){
            window.plugins.ChildBrowser.showWebPage("http://www.google.com");
        }
});
return LoginView;
 });
```

Any ideas?